# How can I submit multiple dynamically generated forms with a single submit button using Javascript? [partial progress]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am having a bit of trouble with some code.  I am attempting to submit multiple forms.  The first form is immediately visible, and the second can be added to the page when the user clicks an "Add Another Form" button (think of this like a referral system a user can add multiple referrals to).

So far I am able to submit *one* form and make more than one form appear on the page, however submitting any more than the first visible form is a challenge.  Here is my code so far:

The form (all forms are clones):

```
<form action="www.example.com/submission.php" name="contactform" method="POST" class="biggerForm">
    <input id="name" type="text">
    <input id="phone_number" type="text">
    <input id="addanother" type="button" class="formBtn lrgBtn addanother" value="Add Another Form" >
    <input type="hidden" name="retURL" value="https://www.example.com/thank-you/">
    <input type="button" value="Submit Now" class="loopStarter multiRefHide formBtn" onclick="submitFormLoop()">
</form>
```

JavaScript for Form Submissions (SubmitFormLoop function):

```
var formCounter = 0;
var ellipsesCount = 0;
function submitFormLoop(){
    if(typeof document.forms[formCounter]!= 'undefined'){
        if($('.error:visible').length>0){
            return false;
        }
        document.forms[formCounter].mySubmit.click()
        if($('.error:visible').length>0) return false;

        $('#submitting').show();
        $('#supportCase').hide();
        document.getElementById('submittingText').innerHTML = "Submitting your form(s)."
        setInterval(function(){
        ellipsesCount++;
        var dots = new Array(ellipsesCount % 8).join('.');
        document.getElementById('submittingText').innerHTML = "Submitting your form(s)" + dots;
        }, 300);

        setTimeout(function(){submitFormLoop()},1500)
        formCounter++
    }else{
        window.location = "https://example.com/thank-you";
        $('input[type="submit"],.addanother').hide()
        formCounter = 0;
    }
}
```

Again I can get *the first one* to submit, but I can't seem to get the function to loop.  Any advice on this matter is very welcome, whether it is a small tweak or a recommendation to scrap my code completely.

Thank you all very much.

Comment: can really only do this with ajax...or use one form if using default browser submit. If submitting by default process...each form needs to make an http request...browser can only do one and load one page. Would not take much to submit the first by ajax...then submit the other after that is done. Or submit one and load second on another pageload

Answer (score 2):

You cannot submit multiple [`form`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) elements from the same page.

But you can get the behavior you desire two ways:

1. Submit the forms using AJAX (using [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or a helper library like jQuery).
2. Reformat your inputs to use a single `form` element.

---

To do the latter, PHP programmers<sup>1</sup> typically use the syntax:

```
<form action="www.example.com/submission.php" name="contactform" method="POST" class="biggerForm">
    <input name="contacts[0][name]" type="text">
    <input name="contacts[0][phone_number]" type="text">
    <input name="contacts[1][name]" type="text">
    <input name="contacts[1][phone_number]" type="text">
    <input name="contacts[2][name]" type="text">
    <input name="contacts[2][phone_number]" type="text">
</form>
```

Notice the `[<integer>]` in the syntax. In PHP, the `$_POST` variable will contain data like these as an indexed array.

Your button can then add additional `input` elements in the same format:

```
<input name="contacts[3][name]" type="text">
<input name="contacts[3][phone_number]" type="text">
```

On form submission, you can then retrieve these fields like so:

```
foreach($_POST['contacts'] as $person){
    echo $person['name'];
    echo $person['phone_number'];
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> I assume you're using PHP since your form's endpoint is `submission.php`.

Comment: First and foremost, thank you for your response!  I will attempt to integrate this and let you know if it works.